# html form calls javascript function and its submit button returns false

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form which calls a java script function, this is the form tag:

```
<form name="myForm1" method="post" action="test" onsubmit=" updateTable();">
```

and the submit button of this form inserts data in the database, but after inserting it moves to a blank page, I want it to stay in the same page to insert more data, this is the javascript function:

```
function updateTable() {
    tabBody = document.getElementById("editable");
    row = document.createElement("tr");
    cellID = document.createElement("td");
    cellname = document.createElement("td");
    cellID.innerHTML = document.forms['myForm1'].elements[1].value;
    cellname.innerHTML = document.forms['myForm1'].elements[0].value;
    row.appendChild(cellID);
    row.appendChild(cellname);
    if (tabBody.childNodes.length == 10) {
        tabBody.removeChild(tabBody.childNodes[0])  
    }

    document.getElementById("mytb").style.display = "block";
    tabBody.appendChild(row);
}
```

and this is the code of the button:

```
<input id="SaveBtn" name="SaveBtn" type="submit" value="حفظ" onclick="return false;">
```

and return false doesn't work.

Does any one have a solution?

Comment: It would help if you provided a [live test case](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). I'd expect the code you have to have a different effect to what you describe, but it doesn't make sense for everyone to who wants to help you to reverse engineer your code to build enough HTML to run it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `preventDefault()`?

```
function updateTable(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    tabBody = document.getElementById("editable");
    row = document.createElement("tr");
    cellID = document.createElement("td");
    cellname = document.createElement("td");
    cellID.innerHTML = document.forms['myForm1'].elements[1].value;
    cellname.innerHTML = document.forms['myForm1'].elements[0].value;
    row.appendChild(cellID);
    row.appendChild(cellname);
    if (tabBody.childNodes.length == 10) {
        tabBody.removeChild(tabBody.childNodes[0])  
    }

    document.getElementById("mytb").style.display = "block";
    tabBody.appendChild(row);

    return false;
}
```

EDIT:
As pointed out in comment below. You'll have to pass the event too.

```
<form name="myForm1" method="post" action="test" onsubmit=" updateTable(event);">
```

Comment: The first argument to `updateTable` isn't the event, since the function is being called *from the event handler* and isn't the event handler itself.

Comment: @DÏnaAtef Event itself. Try the updated code above. Should work.

Comment: No, js function wasn't called.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `return false;` at the end of your `updateTable()` function.

This will prevent the form submission to complete.

Answer (score 0):

If return false doesn't work. You can also try to get the first argument (the event) and prevent the default action on it:

```
function updateTable( event ){
    // do your stuff
    // ...
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The first argument to `updateTable` isn't the event, since the function is being called from the event handler and isn't the event handler itself.

Answer (score -2):

Don’t use the `onsubmit` property.

```
<form name="myForm1" method="post" action="test" onsubmit=" updateTable();">
```

Use `onclick` like below. Control will remain in same page.

```
<form name="myForm1" onclick=" updateTable();">
```

In the `updateTable()` function use AJAX call to insert the data.

Comment: DÏna Atef want to insert the data into a database.....To prevent the page  from redirecting "onclick" is one of the best option and "ajax" for inserting data in to database

Comment: hmm, missed that. This won't prevent the form from submitting normally though and "use Ajax" isn't a complete answer.